# navigation bar - how to make it repsonsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a navigation bar which is build from:

```html
<div>
  <span>Some Text</span>
  <ul>
    <li>Item1</li>
    <li>Item2</li>
    <li>Item3</li>
    <li>Item4</li>
    <li>Item5</li>
  </ul>
  <select>
    <option>Option1</option>
    <option>Option2</option>
    <option>Option3</option>
    <option>Option4</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

I was wondering how to take this navigation bar which was already built and make it responsive as the browser window resizes.

The website is in production and can't waste any time building it all over again.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is multiple ways you could do this, easiest method would be once viewport has reached the size you want whether that be mobile or tablet. Add a burger button in to replace the navigation bar. Little styling and you can make it look very professional.

https://github.com/viljamis/responsive-nav.js

I found this link that goes into quite some detail about this and could be helpful.

Example:

```
@media (max-width: 1024px) { /*This is your tablet view */
  .navigation_bar {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 600px) { /*This is your mobile view view */
  .navigation_bar {
    display: none;
    /* In your mobile view you would display your current navigation bar to:
       display: none; and then change the class on your burger button image. */
  }
  .burger-button-nav {
   display: block;
}
```